# Is the statement, "By definition, energy transferred as radiation is energy transferred as work" true?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, radiation

Here's a photo of the source of this statement: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2V1j8ZwGcPcYWZqTE41NTFtOWoyUUU4SHkwR3c5M00tbWxv)

I can't really google this one because the term "work" is so general it just fails. And I can't find any good texts that explicity state whether radiation is work or heat.

Please this is driving me crazy, I personally don't believe this, but I'm not a PhD like the author. Although he does have a reputation of being controversial.

Edit: I don't see how this question is unclear, as it is a true or false question. Is radiation work?

Comment: the link doesn't work.

Comment: it's difficult to tell as the link is not working but "work" is the term used for mechanical energy so just from the statement in the title this doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Energy transferred due to temperature difference is considered heat and not work.

Comment: The link doesn't work, and until you give us some more information I don't see how we can answer this.

Comment: Even with the working link, this is still unclear.  What would be more helpful is a clear statement of the definition that's being used.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert What do you mean? The definition being used is clearly stated as “**By definition**, energy transferred as radiation is energy transferred as work”.

Comment: If that's exactly the definition that's being used, then the question is tautological:  it's true because the author has defined it to be true.  What I think you're really interested in asking is "Is this a standard definition, and if not, why would the author define it this way?"  For that we need more background.

Comment: Hi UnicodeAlt255. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 2):

The author is probably asserting he is using a convention where all energy transfer from radiation sources is catalogized as work, not heat.

Such convention can make sense in certain situations, for example if the transfer is due to very regular EM wave like harmonic plane wave.

However, it is not appropriate for thermal radiation that is emitted by every body with non-zero temperature. The latter is also called heat radiation and transfer of energy through such radiation is macroscopically more similar to heat transfer than to work transfer.